# Resampling audio output for A2DP (from PCM WAV)

Tags: audio, bluetooth, resampling, a2dp

How do I bring stereo `PCM WAV 32,000Hz` with a stream of `1024 kbps (125 KB)` to the headset with Bluetooth 2.1 on a CM7 smartphone with `DSPManager`? Is this possible? *SBC is really a bad idea.*

Maybe it's possible with the Headset Profile (HSP)? I don`t know about supported codecs in this profile.

*@TJD: Because it compresses the compressed stream. My Epic 4G don`t have Apt-X support. My headset Gemix BH-04A yellow.*

Comment: What kind of headset?  Why do you way SBC is a bad idea?

Comment: A2DP can't be used to send uncompressed PCM.  The profile allows for a variety of codecs, but SBC is the only required codec, and both ends of the connection must agree on a commonly supported choice.  Vast majority of connections will just use SBC, but some devices support MP3, AAC, or AptX

Comment: I get it. Thanks for the reply. Headset Profile can only support mono channel, but in PCM. Still, how to get a headset to take raw audio. Is it impossible?